# How to workaround same origin problem

Tags: javascript

The following JS will fail if the URL in mainFrame from **a.abc.com to b.abc.com**.

top.frames["mainFrame"].location.href = "/Users/xuenn.aspx?backUrl=" + top.frames["mainFrame"].location.href.split("?")[0];

This is the error message:
Permission denied for http://a.abc.com to get property Location.href from http://b.abc.com.

Anybody knows how could I workaround this or think of other solutions?

Comment: What are you looking to get back from the server? If it's JSON, try building it out as JSONP instead. If you're reading back text, HTML or XML, it's more difficult.

Comment: And how did you deduce that he was trying to retrieve anything from the server? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Access to [window]s from other domains are prohibited by the Same Origin Policy, the `location` property is however writable.

In this case, you need to either use `document.domain = foo`, or in some other way pass the expected url to `a.abc.com`, for instance using `#http://b.abc.com/` or `?b=http://b.abc.com/` so that you don't need to read the property.

In the first case, note that this might create problems with scripts that use iframes to post/upload data to the server asynchronously as these will no longer have access to the iframes content after setting `document.domain`.

If your environment is cross-domain then you should probably look into [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) as well. This is a easy-to-use library that lets you communicate across domain boundaries, event with RPC calls. You can try one of the examples [here](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/xhr.html), this enables cross-domain XHR.
Read more about the example at http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/